# Utilizar el SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) con MariaDB 10.1.21

Tags: visual-studio, mariadb, ssrs

Me gustaría saber que version del SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) tengo que instalar con el Visual Studio para poder utilizar el SSRS con MariaDB 10.1.21.

Y que version del driver ODBC necesito para la conexion del Visual Studio con la base de datos MariaDB.

Aqui os dejo un enlace con las posibles descargas:
[SSDT](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017)

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para usar SSRS con mariadb 10.1.21 Puedes usar las SSDT para VS2015 y el driver odbc 5.1.13 para mysql